# Duration limit on applicationDidEnterBackground (iOS) and onPause()/onStop()?

Tags: android, ios, background

This question is about background handling on iOS and Android. On iOS the platform will call

```
applicationDidEnterBackground
```

to notify the app that it is sent to background. On Android the calls are

```
onPause()/onStop()
```

depending on version prior or since HONEYCOMB. What is the duration time for the functions to complete, or are they always guaranteed to complete (i.e. without the platform killing the app before finish)?